# jQuery hide, show, delay,fadeout, empty div script

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery to do something simple ... i'm a student.
I have a div named error, and if div has no text in it i want it to be hidden. But if text goes into it i want it to appear or fade in, and appear for a few seconds and then fade back out and remove the text from the div.

Please can you tell me what you did to fix my thing so i can learn from it please?

Here is my script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($("#error").text().length != 0) {
     $("#error").show().delay(2800).fadeOut().empty();
   }    
  else if($("#error").text().length == 0){
       $("#error").hide();
   }
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`empty` is not an animation, and hence is not placed in your animations queue. It will be executed immediately. Call it in a callback instead:

```
...delay(2800).fadeOut(function() {
   $(this).empty();
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kaatax0n/)

If you're having other issues, it helps if you describe what exact problem you're facing. Note that `.text.length` won't be zero if you have whitespace in the div.

Answer (score 2):

use 
$(this).empty(); instead of direct empty()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#error').bind("DOMNodeInserted",function(){

  if ($("#error").text().length != 0) {
     $("#error").fadeIn();
     setTimeout (function(){
     $("#error").delay(2800).fadeOut().empty()
     },1000);
   }    
  else if($("#error").text().length == 0){
       $("#error").hide();
   }
});
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#error").text().length != 0) {
        $("#error").hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(2500);
        $("#error").hide().delay(1000).fadeOut(2500, function() {
            $("#error").empty();
        });
    }    
    else if($("#error").text().length == 0){
        $("#error").hide();
    }
});
```

Display div content from hidden state with a delay and fadeIn:

```
$("#error").hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(2500);
```

Return div content to a hidden state with a delay and fadeOut + a callback to empty your div:

```
$("#error").hide().delay(1000).fadeOut(2500, function() {
    $("#error").empty();
});
```

I've tested it on my xampp localhost and it does the job well.

Cheers!